# Is there anyway to have a decltype on a template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

quick question. If I have a function signature like

```
template <typename T, typename ItType>
ItType binarySearch ( T mid, ItType first, ItType last );
```

Is there anyway to do something like the following? I know this syntax isn't correct but you get the idea as I can do a decltype similar with regular functions see below. The compiler knows the type of ItType at compile time so shouldn't it be able to deduce the type of *ItType as well?

```
template <typename ItType>
ItType binarySearch ( decltype(*ItType) mid, ItType first, ItType last );


// lambda
auto p = v.begin() + (v.end() - v.begin())/2;
std::partition ( v.begin(), v.end(), [p](decltype(*p) i) { return i < *p; } )
```

Comment: `std::iterator_traits<ItType>::value_type &` maybe?

Comment: Or `decltype( *std::declval<It>() )`

Comment: Why the restriction? I.e. why aren't you satisfied with the first version?

Comment: @DyP To improve the error message in case of a wrong parameter maybe? And it's just an example, the general problem should be solved with [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

Comment: @DanielFrey Then, what about `static_assert`? IMO, one should test if comparisons between `*first` and `mid` are well-formed, e.g. via `is_convertible< decltype(mid < *first), bool >{}` (Of course, this requires `declval` if it shall use SFINAE.)

Comment: @DyP In this example it's an option, but I understood the OP to ask the more general question on how to use a type (possibly from a template parameter) in an expression within `decltype`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with

```
decltype(*ItType)
```

is that `*ItType` is not a valid expression. A naive approach could look like this:

```
decltype(*ItType())
```

which would work *if* `ItType` is default constructible. Since you don't want to enforce that, you can use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to "call" a function that pretends to return an instance of `ItType`:

```
decltype(*std::declval<ItType>())
```

This function is only declared but never defined which means you can not really call it, but that doesn't matter since you are using it within `decltype()`, which is an unevaluated context.

Comment: N.B. If `ItType` is a non-const iterator, the return type of `operator *` will most likely be a non-const ref.

Comment: @DyP Correct, in that case the problem is not wrapping `decltype` into [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay): `typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<ItType>)>::type` and then add a const and a reference as needed... and as with any *specific* example, there might be easier options, OP just needs to know what his options are :)

Comment: `declval<ItType&>()` may generate better results: iirc, `declval<ItType>` ends up with an rvalue reference.

Comment: @Yakk, the reference-ness of `ItType` isn't so important, I think.  The question is the reference of `*ItType*.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid in theory, `*` could return a different type when called on an rvalue than an lvalue.

Comment: @Yakk, that's true.  Given the parameter `ItType first`, should we pass in `ItType` or `ItType&` to declval?  We'll be doing `*first`, and I guess `first` is an lvalue here.  Perhaps the answer is `std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<ItType&>)>::type`.  Using a ref on `ItType&`, and then removing the reference after the `*` because we need to take `mid` by value (or maybe by `const&`).